# adb shell sqlite3 select with special characters error

Tags: shell, sqlite, adb

I am try to retrieve data from sqlite database, but my select query contains special character with resulted in error:

```
adb -s localhost:5558 shell sqlite3 /data/data/com.ocean/databases/announcement.db "select * from announcement where announcement='<1234>';"
```

The adb command return error: /system/bin/sh: can't open 1234': No such file or directory

"<" is a special character, please advice no how to execute query correctly.

Comment: You have to escape the `<` (and probably the quotes) so that the shells on the host and on the devic don't interpret them wrong.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried entering the command after opening the adb shell:

```
adb -s localhost:5558 shell

> sqlite3 /data/data/com.ocean/databases/announcement.db "select * from announcement where announcement='<1234>';"
```

same error?

Comment: hmm very strange. with the quotes exactly like the answer? error `can't open 1234': No such file or directory`